# Can't subscribe to tf with roslibjs

Tags: ros, rosbridge, roslibjs, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Community,

I have a problem with the roslibjs Library. Right now I try to do this tutorial:  [roslibjs TfClient Tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/roslibjs/Tutorials/TfClient)
But I can't get it to work. The rosbridge returns this error:

```
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1445335466.389260] [Client 10] [id: subscribe:/tf2_web_republisher/feedback:4] subscribe: Unable to load the manifest for package tf2_web_republisher. Caused by: tf2_web_republisher
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1445335466.393854] [Client 10] [id: subscribe:/tf2_web_republisher/result:5] subscribe: Unable to load the manifest for package tf2_web_republisher. Caused by: tf2_web_republisher
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1445335466.523221] [Client 10] [id: publish:/tf2_web_republisher/goal:6] publish: Cannot infer topic type for topic /tf2_web_republisher/goal as it is not yet advertised
```

I am not quite sure what this means. Any help is appreciated.

Demian

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/219469/can%27t-subscribe-to-tf-with-roslibjs/) by [Demian23](https://answers.ros.org/users/24665/demian23/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2015-10-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is answered. I am so sorry. I didn't realize that I have to install tf2_we_republisher too.

---

Originally posted by [Demian23](https://answers.ros.org/users/24665/demian23/) with karma: 36 on 2015-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [michaelrosario](https://answers.ros.org/users/26223/michaelrosario/) on 2016-03-09**:
Is there a good procedure for installing tf2_web_republisher?

**Comment by [rtoris288](https://answers.ros.org/users/982/rtoris288/) on 2016-03-09**:
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-tf2-web-republisher

**Comment by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on 2016-10-25**:
FYI this doesn't exist for kinetic (yet)